# Calling member function inside of member function

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to create a member function that takes four inputs, a master list, a key and two secondary lists. It then divides the master list into the two secondary lists based on the key.

This is from a programming book, so there it is required to be a member function.

I'm getting this error: "base operand of "->" has non-pointer type 'UnsortedType'.

This is the whole function that is causing the problem.

```
void UnsortedType::SplitLists(UnsortedType list,
                              ItemType item,
                              UnsortedType& list1,
                              UnsortedType& list2){
    ItemType whichItem;

    int numItems = list.GetLength();

    //Loop through all items in the list
    for(int i = 0; i < numItems; i ++){
        whichItem = list.GetNextItem();
        try{
            switch(whichItem.ComparedTo(item)){
                case LESS:
                case EQUAL:
                    if(list1->isFull()){//Error thrown on this line
                        throw std::string("List1 is full.");
                        return;
                    }
                    //add item to list1
                    list1->PutItem(whichItem);//Error thrown on this line
                break;
                case GREATER:
                    if(list2->isFull()){//Error thrown on this line
                        throw std::string("List2 is full.");
                        return;
                    }
                    //add item to list2
                    list2->PutItem(whichItem);//Error thrown on this line
                break;

            }
        }
        catch(std::string e){
            std::cout << e << std::endl;
        }
    }
};
```

Note that "list1" and "list2" are UnsortedTypes passed by reference, and I think that's part of the problem.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: What programming book would that be?

Comment: "C++ Plus Data Structures" by Dale, Weems and Richard.

Comment: A college class...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

References can be used as though you were just using the original object. If you pass something by reference, then you can just use `.` instead of `->`

```
void UnsortedType::SplitLists(UnsortedType list,
                              ItemType item,
                              UnsortedType& list1,
                              UnsortedType& list2){
    ItemType whichItem;

    int numItems = list.GetLength();

    //Loop through all items in the list
    for(int i = 0; i < numItems; i ++){
        whichItem = list.GetNextItem();
        try{
            switch(whichItem.ComparedTo(item)){
                case LESS:
                case EQUAL:
                    if(list1.isFull()){//Error thrown on this line
                        throw std::string("List1 is full.");
                        return;
                    }
                    //add item to list1
                    list1.PutItem(whichItem);//Error thrown on this line
                break;
                case GREATER:
                    if(list2.isFull()){//Error thrown on this line
                        throw std::string("List2 is full.");
                        return;
                    }
                    //add item to list2
                    list2.PutItem(whichItem);//Error thrown on this line
                break;

            }
        }
        catch(std::string e){
            std::cout << e << std::endl;
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score -1):

You are passing a reference not a pointer.

Type& type // Reference
it is used like type.do_smth()

Type* type // Pointer
it is used like type->do_smth() // because you have to "dereference" it first.

In general a pointer is a wrapper around a reference. A pointer HOLDS a reference to smth.

Comment: "in general a pointer is a wrapper around a reference."  - it never is, A pointer is a basic type of the language.

Comment: When you define a wrapper as a class then yes, it is not a wrapper. But for easy understanding you can say that. But sure you're right.